# Doubts on the correctness of Microsoft Azure Multimedia Services REST API

Tags: rest, http, azure, http-verbs

[The Azure API claims to be a REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj683097.aspx#canceljob). I found it while for patterns and sample implementations and verbs in REST, when inspecting it [in their (supposedly) REST API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj683097.aspx#canceljob), they seem to have invented a new verb `CancelJob` and altering internal state via an HTTP `GET`

```
GET
https://media.windows.net/API/CancelJob?jobid='URL-encodedvalue'
```

This seems to contradict best practices, shall it be implemented with a  `Jobs` resource and `DELETE` or is it correct to do it that way too?

```
DELETE
/API/Jobs?jobid='URL-encodedvalue'
```

Or even?

```
DELETE
/API/Jobs/jobid
```

Comment: What makes you think that this service has any intention of implementing the REST architecture?

Comment: Ha, the title of the page link is "REST API Functions".

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes, because the title of the page says so explicitly. Also, the subtree to the left is called: _Azure Media Services REST API Reference_

Comment: @RaulNoheaGoodness: and now everyone who reads this question will know that the API claims to be a REST API and will not need to ask the same question. The OP should edit the question to include the name of the API, which will be an even better way to make sure that future readers do not need to ask the question that I asked.

Comment: @JohnSaunders absolutely agree, ArielM please edit your question.

Comment: I edited, is it correct this way?

Comment: @ArielM.- I think this question should be closed, because I don't see how anyone outside of the Azure Media Services team will be able to answer your question (you're asking about justification of a specific implementation detail of a product).  That said, your question is specifically about the Media Services API, and the title should be edited to reflect that, not about Azure in general.

Comment: Maybe it should be reformulated on the correctness of REST principles.

Comment: Just did that. So I really want to dig deep into understanding if a REST API can be made like that or is it just them who made it like that. Sorry if it's a dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST has become a buzz word that people use for any API that works over HTTP.  This API appears to be what some people would call REST level 1.  Level 1 means that you use HTTP as a transport mechanism only.  It doesn't respect any of the REST constraints that HTTP is designed for.  I don't think it's fair to call these APIs REST at all, but many still do because REST is popular and business/marketing people what to be able to say they have a REST API.  I suspect that this is the case with this API because the architect(s) of this API clearly put no effort whatsoever into following REST principles.

Comment: Thank you, a big company making such claims is confusing. As i mentioned i found it while looking for some sample REST implementations. This clears such doubts.